# JPQL, HQL conditional insert?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In the sql there is something like

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, city) 
VALUES (10, 'London5') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT sum(customer_id) 
    FROM customers 
    HAVING sum(customer_id) > 20
);
```

*This is not a working example, but still contains the logic I want to achieve.*
I am using spring and hibernate and working with 2 different databases for the same app. So I need something like a custom @Query with jpql or hql so it is able to run on the both DBs. Do you know if that can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you can use a native query instead using dblink for example, Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: hsql and oracle

Comment: If you are using Oracle this can be better read about dblink https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm

Comment: Leaving aside whether it is possible or not in HQL, if this query (eg for ID = 15) will be performed simultaneously in two sessions, then in both sessions the record will be inserted because one session will not see uncommited changes done by another session, and the final sum may be greater than 20. So in the end you will sometimes have errors that are difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @krokodilko so what is the fix? or there is no working fix for that?

Comment: `what is the fix` - perhaps these inserts must be serialized somehow, probably using a lock on some record or on the whole table. But this approach has disadvantages, make the system slower and is not scaleable. But could be that the whole design should be changed. Please explain the wider context, what is the purpose of this insert command, what is the goal ? Could be that you are failing into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and there is a better solution for this problem than this INSERT statement.